# SwiftUI view content layout unexpectedly pop / jumps on appear?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When navigating to a new view with a form, or list (grouped), the content appears about a quarter of the way down from the bottom of the navigation view title, then "pops" up to the correct location about a half second later. Very ugly. Not sure if this is a SwiftUI bug or i'm structuring something incorrectly?

I have tested this on both the simulator and device with same results.

Im thinking it has something to do with the way navigation links are handled? Every navigation link calls the init() on its destination view when ContentView appears. To me this makes no sense, shouldnt the destination init() only be called the moment a user actually clicks the navigation link?

I have tried this with a sheet as well and the problem does not exist with sheets, only when using navigation links with forms or lists styled as grouped.

Code from a brand new single view application:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
                Text("Test Link")
            }
        .navigationBarTitle("Content View")
        }
    }

}

struct TestView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("Test View")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Test View")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Providing a section with a header text fixes the issue, even if the text is blank. Although this will leave a gap between the navigation title and first row.

Works with both Forms & Lists styled as grouped.

```
struct TestView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("")) {
                Text("Test View")
            }
        }
        .nvigationBarTitle("Test View")
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried both of the solutions in this post, still happening. What else could be going on? So strange.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a List that was pushed via NavigationLink from a GroupedListStyle List. When you do that, then it seems that SwiftUI also considers the pushed List as grouped. Just resetting the listStyle should work in this case:

```
List { ... }.listStyle(DefaultListStyle())
```