# SwiftUI: Jump of List Items to headline in a Picker Form

Tags: ios, swiftui, picker, swiftui-navigationlink

Solved: After cleaning the Build Folder and updating to newest xCode version the problem was gone for me.

I have a Navigation View and I am in a Form. My Problem is that in this Form I have a Section with a picker, which brings me by ios default with a navigationLink to a new view, which shows me all my options. This options are in a List, but as soon as this view appears they are a bit below the navgationTitle and after a second they jump up into their correct place. How can I fix this jumping problem? I thnik the problem has something to do with the Picker, because it calls the navigation link internally.

I use XCode 11.5 and here is a sample code that causes the issue:

```
@State var i = 0
var body: some View {
   NavigationView {
     Form {
         Section {
            Picker(selection: $i, label: Text("Pick")) {
                ForEach(0..<5,id: \.self) {
                   Text($0.description)
                }
             }
         }
     }.navigationBarTitle("PickerTest")
   }
}
```

This answer helped me with a very similar issue, but didn't work for this particular case https://stackoverflow.com/a/59591337/13679052

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this in the `init` of your `View`:

```
UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
```

This removes the default space between the `NavigationBar` and the `Form` (and prevents the *jumping* as well). If you want to preserve this space you can specify the `height` to be some other value.

*Note: this will change the `UITableView` behaviour globally and not for this particular `View` only.*